# How to set the og:image from embedded YouTube video in a post (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, syndication

I am using WordPress with the WordPress SEO plugin which automatically sets the og data. I would like to make the og:image set as the YouTube thumbnail if there is an ebedded video in a post. FYI I use dlvr.it to post to social media accounts when I create a post in WordPress. The problem is that a blank thumbnail shows up on Facebook if there is a YouTube embedded video in the post instead of a photo. Does anyone know how to automate this?

Here are links to the blog and rss feed:
http://www.lattianderson.com/blog/
http://www.lattianderson.com/blog/feed/

Answer (score 1):

Using [facebook URL linter tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), you can see that your og:image property is not set properly. You should include only the youtube video id in the URI segment after /vi/ , as in:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/H3GpBGPzcuY?list=PLzD8ebhXjy9RZJdbitJgVbbMqUIjz0c_s/hqdefault.jpg
```

should be

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/H3GpBGPzcuY/hqdefault.jpg
```